# Variance of effects in $2^kr$ factorial design

Tags: self-study, anova, variance, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I'm working through *The Art of Computer Systems Performance Analysis*, a statistics book focused on analyzing computer performance, and I don't follow the logic for computing the variation of effects in the chapter on $2^kr$ factorial designs with replications:

The text uses the following model for a $2^2r$ factorial design:

$$y = q_0 + q_A x_A + q_B x_B + q_{AB} x_A x_B + e$$

> Assume errors are normally distributed with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2_e$, then it follows from the model that the $y_i$'s are also normally distributed with the same variance $\sigma^2_e$. Now consider an effect, for example $q_0$:
>
> $$q_0 = \frac{1}{2^2r} \sum_{i,j}y_{ij}$$
>
> Since $q_0$ is a linear combination of normally distributed variables, it is also normally distributed and its variance is $\sigma^2_e / (2^2r)$.

- Why does the population error variance of $\sigma^2_e$ imply that the variance of $y_i$ is also $\sigma^2_e$?
- What's the connection between $y_i$ having a variance of $\sigma^2_e$ and $q_0$ having a variance of $\sigma^2_e / (2^2r)$? I'm guessing we're dividing by degrees of freedom $2^2r$.

Comment: Please add the tag [tag:self-study]. Q1: Because the other terms are constants (maybe unknown, but not random). Q2: $q_0$ is simply an arithmetic mean, so what is the variance of a mean of independent random variables all with the same variance?